# Additional property files to load in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, config, properties-file, jmeter-5.0

My performance test setup

1. Jmeter 5.3
2. 1 JMX File that contains my test plan.
3. [1 default properties file.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction) This is named 'user.properties'.
4. 1 custom properties file. I pass this when I run my test plan headless.

I have a test plan that I run in the following ways,

1. headless

   jmeter -p "customProp.properties" -n -t "myTestPlan.jmx"
2. GUI

   *Open > myTestPlan.jmx* and like above I want the *customProp.properties* also to come into effect with myTestPlan.jmx in play.

What I've done so far?

1. I've used the 'user.properties' attribute within the *'user.properties'* file in the bin directory as follows,

   *user.properties=customProp.properties*
2. I know how to do add properties files when running headless. Just now sure how to do it with GUI. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any customizations under *user.properties* file and don't plan to have them in the future - locate the following line in the ***jmeter.properties*** file:

```
user.properties=user.properties
```

and change it to point to your "custom" properties file:

```
user.properties=customProp.properties
```

it will make the change permanent and you won't have to play with command-line arguments no matter whether you run JMeter in GUI or non-GUI modes (JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up)

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 2):

Just proceed as for Non GUI, but note it’s better to make -p point to jmeter.properties and -q to user.properties and your additional properties file:

> jmeter -p path_to_jmeter.properties -q path_to_user.properties -q path_to_custom.properties

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

Comment: I was missing the following pieces of knowledge. 
1. I can always drop the -n and run JMeter with GUI. 
2. Option -p, --propfile <argument>
        the jmeter property file to use. I put my jmeter.properties file which I have left untouched. 
3. Option -q, --addprop <argument>
        additional JMeter property file(s) such as the customProp.properties

Comment: Hello, just wondering why my answer is not the accepted one while it was the first one and is the correct one. Thanks